# How scalars appear in Goldstone's theorem

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry-breaking, goldstone-mode

Let $G$ be a lie group and $G_i$ its generators. Suppose for a set of fields $\chi_{\alpha}(x)$ we have
$$
\left[G_{i}, \chi_{\alpha}(x)\right]=-\left(g_{i}\right)_{\alpha \beta} \chi_{\beta}(x)
$$

If the Lagragian $\mathcal{L}$ is invariant under the $G$ then we have the conserved charges
$$
G_{i} \equiv Q_{i}=\int d^{3} x J_{i}^{o}=\int d^{3} x\left[\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \partial_{o} \chi_{\alpha}} \frac{1}{i}\left(g_{i}\right)_{\alpha \beta} \chi_{\beta}\right]
$$
Suppose that
$$
\left\langle 0\left|\left[G_{i}, \chi_{\alpha}(x)\right]\right| 0\right\rangle=-\left(g_{i}\right)_{\alpha \beta}\left\langle 0\left|\chi_{\beta}(x)\right| 0\right\rangle \neq0.
$$
then we have $$
\begin{aligned}
\left(g_{i}\right)_{\alpha \beta}\left\langle 0\left|\chi_{\beta}(x)\right| 0\right\rangle=& \sum_{n} \int d^{3} y\left\{\left\langle 0\left|e^{-i P y} J_{i}^{o}(0) e^{i P y}\right| n\right\rangle\left\langle n\left|\chi_{\alpha}(x)\right| 0\right\rangle\right.\\
&\left.-\left\langle 0\left|\chi_{\alpha}(x)\right| n\right\rangle\left\langle n\left|e^{-i P y} J_{i}^{o}(0) e^{i P y}\right| 0\right\rangle\right\} \\
=& \sum_{n} \int d^{3} y e^{i P_{n} y}\left\langle 0\left|J_{i}^{o}(0)\right| n\right\rangle\left\langle n\left|\chi_{\alpha}(x)\right| 0\right\rangle \\
&-\sum_{n} \int d^{3} y e^{-i P_{n} y}\left\langle 0\left|\chi_{\alpha}(x)\right| n\right\rangle\left\langle n\left|J_{i}^{o}(0)\right| 0\right\rangle \\
=& \sum_{n}(2 \pi)^{3} \delta^{3}\left(\vec{p}_{n}\right)\left\{e^{-i P_{n}^{o} y^{o}}\left\langle 0\left|J_{i}^{o}(0)\right| n\right\rangle\left\langle n\left|\chi_{\alpha}(x)\right| 0\right\rangle\right.\\
&\left.-e^{+i P_{n}^{o} y^{o}}\left\langle 0\left|\chi_{\alpha}(x)\right| n\right\rangle\left\langle n\left|J_{i}^{o}(0)\right| 0\right\rangle\right\}
\end{aligned}
$$
By assumption this expression does not vanish and, furthermore, since the LHS is independent of $y^{o}$ it must also be independent of $y^{o} .$ Clearly this can only happen if in the theory there exist some massless one-particle states $|n\rangle$ and only these states contribute to the sum.

This is the proof that I found of Goldstone theorem .

But the proof only shows that particles are massless .
How do we show that these particles are scalars and how the fields $\phi_i$ associated with this $$|p,i\rangle$$ particles transform under the group $G$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, Lorentz symmetry [can be spontaneously broken](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54279). That phenomenon is beyond the scope of the present question, though, so for this answer I'll assume that Lorentz symmetry is *not* spontaneously broken.

In this case, the vacuum state is Lorentz invariant: if $U$ is the unitary operator implementing a Lorentz transform, then $U|0\rangle=|0\rangle$. The condition implies
$$
 \langle 0| \chi' |0\rangle
 =
 \langle 0|U^\dagger \chi U|0\rangle
 =
 \langle 0| \chi |0\rangle
$$
where $\chi'\equiv U^\dagger \chi U$ is the Lorentz transform of $\chi$. This says that the vacuum expectation value of $\chi$ is invariant under Lorentz transformations, so either $\chi$ is a scalar or its vacuum expectation value is zero. The assumption of SSB is that its vacuum expectation value is nonzero, so $\chi$ must be a scalar field. Then the only single-particle states that $\chi$ can create from the vacuum are scalars, so if $|n\rangle$ is a one-particle state, then the factor $\langle 0|\chi|n\rangle$ cannot be nonzero unless that particle is a scalar.